# How do I look for whats blocking UWP from reaching an API

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an UWP application one client cannot retreive data from the API. She had the application installed and working, but after an update this single client cannot access data from API, none of the API calls succeeds, all fails with error: A connection with the server could not be established.

We have checked the users internet-access and that the user has access to the API from that machine, we have tried Postman so the machine can access the API. But when the application tries to access API it does not reach the API.

I have checked the firewall and the app is allowed there on all three profiles. We have capabilities in the manifest for both internet and privateNetworkClientServer. (it works on all other machines, but stopped working after an update, not even older versions works from that machine any more).

The log files does not say anything either.

Where can I look for stuff that might block UWP traffic?

*edit*
We added the internetClientServer capability and then it worked.

Comment: Have you added permission to access the internet in your app?  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
  </Capabilities> in appmanifest file

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark to see what actually happens to the traffic?

Comment: Yes, the permission is added,

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] for us?